# Dynamic Web Service application in VB

Tags: vb.net, web-services, web-config

The problem that I am running into is that I can not get my application to dynamically access a seperate applications webservice when using different enviornments. I understand I need to make the url dynamic and alter the infromation in the config file. I am unsure about the steps needed to take when the webservice is a Service Reference insted of a Web Reference(there are alot of tutorials that show you can right click > properties > and select dynamic URL behavior. This doesnt work for service referenec) How do I go about configuring this at runtime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not invoke the web service dynamically in your code instead of playing with static references?

I've been using this code for a long time, can't remember where I got it though:

```
    Friend Class WsProxy
    <SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Unrestricted:=True)> _
    Friend Shared Function CallWebService(ByVal webServiceAsmxUrl As String, ByVal serviceName As String, ByVal methodName As String, ByVal args As Object()) As Object
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf bypassAllCertificateStuff)
        Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()

        ' Connect To the web service
        Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = client.OpenRead(webServiceAsmxUrl & "?wsdl")

        ' Now read the WSDL file describing a service.
        Dim description As ServiceDescription = ServiceDescription.Read(stream)

        '''// LOAD THE DOM /////////
        ' Initialize a service description importer.
        Dim importer As New ServiceDescriptionImporter()

        importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12"
        ' Use SOAP 1.2.
        importer.AddServiceDescription(description, Nothing, Nothing)
        ' Generate a proxy client.
        importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client
        ' Generate properties to represent primitive values.
        importer.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties

        ' Initialize a Code-DOM tree into which we will import the service.
        Dim nmspace As New CodeNamespace()
        Dim unit1 As New CodeCompileUnit()
        unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace)

        ' Import the service into the Code-DOM tree. This creates proxy code that uses the service.
        Dim warning As ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1)
        If warning = 0 Then
            ' If zero then we are good to go
            ' Generate the proxy code
            Dim provider1 As CodeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp")

            ' Compile the assembly proxy with the appropriate references
            Dim assemblyReferences As String() = New String(4) {"System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll"}
            Dim parms As New CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences)
            Dim results As CompilerResults = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1)

            ' Check For Errors
            If results.Errors.Count > 0 Then
                For Each oops As CompilerError In results.Errors
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("========Compiler error============")
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(oops.ErrorText)
                Next
                Throw New System.Exception("Compile Error Occured calling webservice. Check Debug ouput window.")
            End If

            ' Finally, Invoke the web service method
            Dim wsvcClass As Object = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceName)
            Dim mi As MethodInfo = wsvcClass.[GetType]().GetMethod(methodName)
            Return mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, args)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function

    Private Shared Function bypassAllCertificateStuff(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal cert As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal [error] As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

To use it, just make an array of type Object with the parameters like this:

```
Dim vParams(1) As Object
vParams(0) = "Some param"  ' Some string parameter
vParams(1) = 12345  ' Some integer parameter
```

Then invoke using a static call to the class:

```
WsProxy.CallWebService("http://yourserviceurlhere/", "WsNamespace", "MethodName", vParams)
```

This will produce a response of type Object with whatever the web service response was. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks reno812, however I am referencing objects auto created by entity framework in the web-service application. Do not believe i can do that using this method :/

Comment: Yeah, no problem, it was worth a shot I guess.